# Android Studio and Eclipse - which one I should use?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-studio, ide

I want to develop some Android applications. I have had Google trying to find out how I should choose between Android Studio and Eclipse, but I don't know how I should choose between these two **IDEs**.

On many websites, I see developers more likely to use **Eclipse** than **Android Studio**, or it is because **Android Studio** was just released?

So which one should I choose?

Comment: you should use android studio

Comment: Use Android studio for android development. Google has stopped support for eclipse ADT

Answer (score 2):

> **Important**: Support for the Android Developer Tools (ADT) in Eclipse is ending, per our announcement. You should migrate your app development projects to Android Studio as soon as possible. For more information on transitioning to Android Studio, see Migrating to Android Studio.
>   [Reference for the quote.](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html)

So definitively, you should use Android Studio

Answer (score 1):

You still may be more productive with Eclipse at the time of writing, as Android studio is relatively new and some obvious features (like Unit testing, for instance) are kind of present yet you just cannot get them working. It will pass many years till Android 6.0 applications you can develop with Eclipse no problem will no longer run on majority of devices on the market.

But as Android studio will likely to improve over time, and  new features will be available only there in the future, I would recommend to start from that IDE for a complete beginner. Even better it may be to understand how the command line development works as this may allow to use any flexible enough IDE, does not matter is it officially supported on not.