# why i cant find Android SDK that works on eclipse on Eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk, adt

I found this on developer.android.com, is that mean that I can't use Eclipse to develope Android aps??

P.S. : I use Ubuntu 15.04 64 bits

"Important: Support for the Android Developer Tools (ADT) in Eclipse has ended, per our announcement. You should migrate your app development projects to Android Studio as soon as possible. For more information on transitioning to Android Studio, see Migrating from Eclipse ADT. "

Comment: The answer is in your question: `Support for the Android Developer Tools (ADT) in Eclipse has ended`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I don't like to cite someone, but this explanation of above problem is pretty enough good:

> You still may be more productive with Eclipse at the time of writing,
> as Android studio is relatively new and some obvious features (like
> Unit testing, for instance) are kind of present yet you just cannot
> get them working. It will pass many years till Android 6.0
> applications you can develop with Eclipse no problem will no longer
> run on majority of devices on the market.
>
> But as Android studio will likely to improve over time, and new
> features will be available only there in the future, I would recommend
> to start from that IDE for a complete beginner. Even better it may be
> to understand how the command line development works as this may allow
> to use any flexible enough IDE, does not matter is it officially
> supported on not.
>
> From: [Android Studio and Eclipse - which one I should use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31221630/android-studio-and-eclipse-which-one-i-should-use/31221665)

For beginners who just started Android Development, it's good to start with Eclipse because of many tutorials and books are based on using Eclipse with ADT plugin.

But look... there you would not find big projects with some libraries and dependencies or modules, but `TicTacToe`, simple GPS Provider who would tell you where you actually are or `ImageGallery`.

Notice also how many StackOverflow question tagged with `android` and `eclipse` tags are because of incompatibility of dependency, module or library. Take your time and have a look into it.

Times are changing... Two years ago there wasn't Android Studio and today's must-have libraries like `Picasso` or `Robolectric`.

Hope it help you to understand above statement.

Answer (score 0):

Technically speaking, you still can use Eclipse to develop Android apps.

But from the beginning of 2015 it becomes more hard and harder - Google not only stopped ADT development, but also moved all his Android samples to gradle-based directory structure. It means that rare link to sources from developer.android.com is not broken now ;-(

Also, the majority of independent software components and libraries developers stopped Eclipse support. And new libraries are distributed from `jcenter()` and other maven-like repositories. It may be hard to get library jar to put into your project `libs/` directory.

It would be preferable to start with Android Studio in 2016, without touching Eclipse at all.